# JPanel create empty space between subPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm developing a `Java` application for homework. This is my code

```
 JLabel queryHandlerL = new JLabel("Create php to handle query results", JLabel.CENTER);
 final JCheckBox queryHandlerCB = new JCheckBox();
 JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
 checkBoxPanel.add(queryHandlerL);
 checkBoxPanel.add(queryHandlerCB);
 
 // Query Panel
 // set image
 picLabelQuery = new JLabel("",JLabel.LEFT);
 picLabelQuery.setIcon(currentPicForm);
 
 JPanel queryPanel = new JPanel();
 final JButton queryButton = new JButton("Insert a query");
 
 queryPanel.add(queryButton);
 queryPanel.add(picLabelQuery);
 
 // Panel create
 final JButton createButton = new JButton("Create");
 JPanel createPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
 createPanel.add(createButton);
 
 
 JPanel finalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1,5,2)); 
 finalPanel.add(queryPanel);
 finalPanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
 finalPanel.add(createPanel);
 
 finalPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("SQL connection"));

 setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
 add(finalPanel);
```

I have a `CardLayout` and this is a `Window` inside this `CardLayout`. The last `add(finalPanel)` refers to the panel of the `CardLayout`.

This piece of code works but this is the result
[image]

How do I remove the space that is automatically created between the panels?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  Note that calling `pack()` on the frame containing a `CardLayout` will make it as small as needed to display the **largest** panel.  I suspect that is the problem here.  Other panels in the card layout require more space.

Comment: That's probably true, but how can solve this?can't i set the empty space at the bottom of the window?

Comment: *"how can solve this?"*  You might start by taking the advice I offered in the first sentence of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I remove the space that is automatically created between the panels?

Use a different layout manager for the panel. The GridLayout will always resize components to take up all the space in the panel.

Maybe you can use a BoxLayout or a GridBagLayout. You can also nest panels with different layout managers to get your desired effect.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should `pack()` your surrounding panel or set the height to a desired value.

Comment: Could you give a sample code i should add to pack() the panels?

Comment: After you added all sub-panels, simply call `pack()` on the panel which contains all sub-panels.

Comment: Can i pack() panels?? `finalPanel.pack();` gives me an error